# Is it possible with Dozer to map from Java Object to xml?

Tags: java, xml, dozer

What i want is:

I have a java DTO object...simple getters setters (dates,string, int..so on) and i want to generate from the jva object to a xml string..so for example:

```
DTOclass{
    int id;
    String name;
    //Getters-settters
}
```

and i want to create like:

```
<id>dto.getId()</id> <!--With dozer of course...just call a map method and somehow i create a string from that-->
<name>dto.getName()</name>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @kodaek98 if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and up-voting it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with Dozer. The very first line of the [About](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/about.html) page states it's meant for mapping Java Beans to each other (and nothing else).

Maybe you could get creative and find another library to use in conjunction with Dozer.